# React App renders blank page when deployed on server

Tags: reactjs, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm pretty new to web development and servers but for a project I had to deploy a React app on a server that runs Nginx. I followed some resources from the Internet and found that is enough to run
`yarn build` and copy the files from the **build** directory to the server.

Since I wanted to have the application at the link: https://hostname:5000/app, I copied the files to `/var/www/html/app` and I made the following changes to the configuration in Nginx:

```
server {
  listen <IP>:5002 ssl http2;
  listen <IP>:5001;

  ssl_certificate <path_to>/cert.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key <path_to>key.pem;

  location /app {
    root /var/www/html/;
    index /app/index.html;
  }


  location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:request.sock;
   }

}
```

On the React app side, I added in `package.json` the line: `"homepage":".",`.

Unfortunately, when I access the link, it displays a blank page and after checking with the browser's devtools I found that there are no errors. Moreover, the same configuration is able to render the demo application that is provided when you create a new React app.

I tried different solutions from the internet but unfortunately, it didn't work. React version is `"react": "^18.2.0",`.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Never mind the question. It was not a problem on the server side. The React app developer figured out that by setting the homepage in package.json and changing from BrowserRoute to HashRoute will make it work.